# 'Test Mail Server Tool' only working in certain cases?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm currently using **Test Mail Server Tool** to send emails through the locahost server I have set up (**WAMP**).

For some reason, the first two e-mails I send work just fine (they show up in the received mail folder), but the other email that is sent from a different PHP file never shows up or mails. The function was working just fine, I didn't change anything. I even did some debugging to see where the code was going wrong - it goes right up to the function and then just doesn't work.

However - when I put the files on another computer, the function seems to work just fine. I made sure I have Skype and any other messaging service that takes up ports closed. I tried restarting my computer, restarting WAMP server and the tool, nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: standard email debugging: check the smtp server's logs to see what happened after php handed over the email,  and what happened if/when the smtp server tried to forward the email onwards.

Comment: @MarcB I know my code is working, it just suddenly stopped emailing I suppose. It's only for this file though, that makes me suspicious.